# localization and wrong keyboard for password field

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, localization

I have a password text field (secured), and from some reason when I change the language of the OS, the english keyboard comes up for the password field only, rather than the keyboard for the selected language. Does anyone ever seen this issue? How can this be fixed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the other language you're testing with isn't a language with a standard input keyboard (such as French, Spanish) but a language with a [complex input method](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/StringsTextFonts/Conceptual/TextAndWebiPhoneOS/KeyboardManagement/KeyboardManagement.html), then I believe what you are seeing is, unfortunately, standard iOS behaviour.

See the issue as described here:
[why can't I use secureTextEntry with a UTF-8 keyboard?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9944769/why-cant-i-use-securetextentry-with-a-utf-8-keyboard) and here (with a solution): [Selecting language of the keyboard for UITextField with secureTextEntry](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6828834/selecting-language-of-the-keyboard-for-uitextfield-with-securetextentry)